# How to Avoid inconsistent OutOfMemory Exceptions with BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray?

Tags: java, android, bitmapfactory

I have the following code for my android App:

```
private PictureCallback pictureTakenCallback = new PictureCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        Bitmap bmp = null;
        Bitmap scaledBitmap = null;
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = null;

        showLoading(true);//UI crap

        try
        {
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length); //OOM Exception Thrown Here

            //if the bitmap is smaller than 1600 wide, scale it up while preserving aspect ratio
            if(bmp.getWidth() < 1600) {
                int originalHeight = bmp.getHeight();
                int originalWidth = bmp.getWidth();

                scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, 1600,
                        originalHeight*1600/originalWidth, true);

                bmp = scaledBitmap;
                scaledBitmap = null;
            }

            baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 30, baos); // 30% compression
            image = baos.toByteArray();

            submitImage();
        }
        catch (java.lang.OutOfMemoryError e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            showLoading(false);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            showLoading(false);
        }
        finally
        {
            bmp = null;

            if (baos != null) {
                try {
                    baos.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            baos = null;
        }
    }
};
```

Sometimes I get users complaining of out of memory exceptions being thrown to their phone. I never run into this problem with my devices, could this be related to their phones having insufficient memory?

Can someone look at this code and give me tips on how to make it more efficient?
Thanks!

Comment: try this http://voidcanvas.com/whatsapp-like-image-compression-in-android/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always try to  **android:largeHeap="true"** in Manifest like this

```
<application 
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        >
```

Answer (score 0):

You can load scaled down version into memory

You need to look at [Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) developer site